# Sorting from two column with WHERE and BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, where-clause

afflicted with a project in which you have to do to seek by category and by price:
I got the following mysql code:
`$query = " SELECT * FROM filmi WHERE $id3 = '1' $orderby_query "`

`filmi` is the main table , 
`$id3 = '1'` is the secondary table for the category. 
and `$orderby_query` is simple order by price desc/asc

How do I search by price range ?  between  10 and 100 ? i cant use `WHERE seriq BETWEEN 50000 AND 1000000 ORDER by seriq asc` , because already got where :(

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   WHERE $id3 = '1'
   AND seriq BETWEEN 50000 AND 1000000
   ORDER by seriq asc
```

or like that

```
   WHERE $id3 = '1'
   HAVING seriq >= 50000 AND  seriq <= 1000000
   ORDER by seriq asc
```

Comment: Having works like a charm when i just put it into the $query 
but ;\ when i try to put it with the array() its not working 
where my mistake ? http://pastebin.com/LWey93yz

Comment: try this  $query ="SELECT * FROM `filmi` WHERE '$id3' = '1'  '".$orderby_query."' ";

Comment: and u have error here  `$orderby = $_GET[orderby];` change it to `$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];`

Comment: and u have error here `<form method= get  style="display: inline;" name='orderby_form'>` change it to `<form method= "get"  style="display: inline;" name='orderby_form'>`

Comment: and error here `<select name=orderby onChange="orderby_form.submit();">` change it to `<select name="orderby" onchange="orderby_form.submit();">`

Comment: try this code here u have other errors i cant write them all here , try this code http://pastebin.com/JDXPej88

Comment: i try it still doesnt work code is shitty but working ;\ look what i found: when u go to category=1 "http://localhost/movie/category.php?id=1"

and when u choose some sort from form its goes to "http://localhost/movie/category.php?orderby=seriq_asc"

somewhere id=1 its lost :X

Comment: i cant see your code , but in your previous code u have this `$id2` and i dont know how it comes this variable since u gave little code. i cant see your localhost if u send me the link

Comment: i dont have real ip so cant give ya link :( so this is code from index.php where u can choose category: http://pastebin.com/idZYK8Br

then u go to: category.php where is the other code: http://pastebin.com/yaQ5kc0z

Comment: i cant read all ur code sorry. if u know where is the problem i can help u. if u cant try to look your code and debug it and see where is the error .im glad i could help u

Comment: no i dont think the problem is the code i thing i skip something , i use same code in index page for sorting and its working there. The problem comes from this category.php?id=1 and when i sort its changes to category.php?orderby forgot about id=1 witch is the category :( 
ok thank you for time spend i am glad u help me  many thx

Comment: Ок I found where to touch hmm so: how to put in this "orderby" <select name="orderby" onChange="orderby_form.submit();">
This extension: <a href=\"$self&amp;page=$page\" class=\"a\"> $SELF ( & )... and that will work

code works like this: http://localhost/movie/category.php?id=1&orderby=seriq_desc .. so i need to make it $self + &

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple clauses in your `WHERE` criteria just by using `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM filmi
WHERE $id3 = '1' AND
   seriq BETWEEN 50000 AND 1000000
ORDER by seriq
```

Good luck.